# where is sqlite3 in my aws Ubuntu install?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, sqlite

I just created my first AWS instance of Ubuntu, and used Python to create and load a sqlite3 database-  Now I want to query the loaded database from the command line.  According to the documentation I enter sqlite3  at the command line.  here is my session.

```
└─[$]> sqlite3 fbpost.sqlite
zsh: command not found: sqlite3
```

any ideas on the correct pathname for sqlite3?

Comment: The fact that you may have a sqlite3 driver installed for a given language has no necessary connection to whether you have the sqlite3 command line interface client program installed.  What about `sudo apt-get install sqlite3`?

Comment: That did the trick Thank you @Michael-sqlbot!

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, I 'm guessing you down voted my question- I will delete it

Comment: No, actually... I didn't downvote your question. There isn't a requirement that downvoters offer an explanation of their reasoning, but my tendency is to do that in cases where I believe it will be helpful, informative, or constructive in some way for the post author to understand my reasoning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> any ideas on the correct pathname for sqlite3?

You're asking a sensible question based on what I think to be an incorrect premise.

Premise: you have a python script using a sqlite3 database, and it works, so that means you have "installed sqlite3."

Premise: there's a command line interface (CLI) for sqlite3, but you get `command not found` when you try to run it.

Conclusion:  it must be here somewhere, so you need to find the correct path.

The problem seems to be that it's often possible to have a language-specific driver for a particular database engine installed, but not the CLI for that database engine.  In this specific case, `sudo apt-get install sqlite3` is probably all that is needed, because if it were already installed, it should already be in the search path.